# How many different sums of the dots can one obtain if three ordinary dice are thrown at the same time?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many different sums of the dots can one obtain if three ordinary dice are thrown at the same time? 
>    (an ordinary standard die is a regular cube with its six sides numbered with dots from 1 to 6)?

How should I approach the problem? I have tried to calculate it using combinatorics: ${6 \choose 3}=20$. In this count, we have counted the sum $8$ twice, for example. How can I find all the sums we have counted twice or more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course throw any integer from $3$ $(1,1,1)$ to $18$ $(6,6,6)$, so that gives $18-3 +1  =16$ options.

If you want to count number of the options for each sum, that number for sum $k$ is the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of

$$(x + x^2+ \ldots + x^6)^3$$ which can be found by using standard series expansions.

Comment: I have not studied series expansions. Can you show this for me?

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+polynomial+%28x%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E5%2Bx%5E6%29%5E3) gives the expanded form as $x^{18} + 3 x^{17} + 6 x^{16} + 10 x^{15} + 15 x^{14} + 21 x^{13} + 25 x^{12} + 27 x^{11 }+ 27 x^{10} + 25 x^9 + 21 x^8 + 15 x^7 + 10 x^6 + 6 x^5 + 3 x^4 + x^3$ so you can read off the answers.

Comment: What should I count from this expanded form?

Comment: @NikolDimitrova So there are $21$ ways to throw $13$, $25$ ways to throw $12$ etc.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova $(x+x^2+\ldots x^6)^2= x^2+2x^3+3x^4+4x^5+5x^6+6x^7+5x^8 + 4x^9+3x^{10}+2x^{11}+x^{12}$ is the same principle for two dice.

Comment: But this is not what the problem ask.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova The number of different sums is just $(3 \times 6 - 3 \times 1)+1 = 16$ That's trivial. The hard problem is counting the relative frequencies.

Comment: That's what I am searching for. Can you explain why the number of different sums if just $3.6-3+1=16$?

Comment: @NikolDimitrova That's the number of integers in the interval $[3,18]$, the min and max values.

Comment: This is the number of integers in the interval $[3,18]$. What do you mean by min and max values? Why this count represents the number of different sums?

Comment: @NikolDimitrova Do you agree that the minimum value you can throw with three standard dice is $3$ and the maximal value is $18$? All values inbetween can occur. This is quite obvious.

Comment: Oh, yes I see this.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova The number of integers is te largest  one minus the smallest one plus 1 (one die is $6-1 + 1 = 6$ options etc. ) Classic off by one error to forget the $+1$ here. $[1,2]$ has two integers and length 1, $[1,3]$ has three and length 2, etc. generalise to $[3,18]$ and we get $16$.